# `pyyaml` can't parse `pydantic` object if `typing` module is used

Tags: python, pydantic, pyyaml

Let me start off by saying I wanted to open an issue in `pydantic` repo. Once I started rubber duck debugging I came up to the conclusion it's actually `pyyaml` that isn't working right but I'm not so sure anymore.

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from functools import partial
from typing import List, Type

import yaml
from pydantic import BaseModel

yaml_input = """
!Foo
name: foo
bar:
    - !Bar
      name: bar
  """


def get_loader():
    loader = yaml.SafeLoader
    for tag_name, tag_constructor in tag_model_map.items():
        loader.add_constructor(tag_name, tag_constructor)
    return loader


def dynamic_constructor_mapping(model_class: Type[BaseModel], loader: yaml.SafeLoader,
                        node: yaml.nodes.MappingNode) -> BaseModel:
    return model_class(**loader.construct_mapping(node))


def get_constructor_for_mapping(model_class: Type[BaseModel]):
    return partial(dynamic_constructor_mapping, model_class)


class Bar(BaseModel):
    name: str


class Foo1(BaseModel):
    name: str
    bar: list


class Foo2(BaseModel):
    name: str
    bar: List


class Foo3(BaseModel):
    name: str
    bar: List[Bar]


@dataclass
class Foo4:
    name: str
    bar: List[Bar]


foos = [Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, Foo4]

for foo_cls in foos:
    tag_model_map = {
        "!Foo": get_constructor_for_mapping(foo_cls),
        "!Bar": get_constructor_for_mapping(Bar),
    }
    print(f"{foo_cls.__qualname__} loaded {yaml.load(yaml_input, Loader=get_loader())}")
```

which prints

```
Foo1 loaded name='foo' bar=[Bar(name='bar')]
Foo2 loaded name='foo' bar=[]
Foo3 loaded name='foo' bar=[]
Foo4 loaded Foo4(name='foo', bar=[Bar(name='bar')])
```

- list of `pydantic` objects is parsed correctly if `list` is used in static typing
- list of `pydantic` objects is **NOT** parsed correctly if `List` is used in static typing
- list of `pydantic` objects is **NOT** parsed correctly if `List[Bar]` is used in static typing
- list of `dataclass` objects is always parsed correctly

The constructor seems to be returning the correct object in all examples so I don't understand where the problem lies.

```
pydantic==1.8.2
Python 3.8.10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same exact issue as you.

The thing that solved the issue for me was setting the `deep` to true in the construct_mapping method.

Example:

```
fields = loader.construct_mapping(node, deep=True)
```

Comment: IIRC that's what I did in the end and it indeed fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

So this is just a problem I've noticed with YAML in general, but it seems to me that code for de/serializing YAML to dataclasses is overall more complicated than needed.

If you don't need the *data validation* features that `pydantic` provides, you could also check out the [`dataclass-wizard`](https://dataclass-wizard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which provides a helper `YAMLWizard` Mixin class that could be used for working with YAML data -- note that this does rely on the `pyyaml` library as well.

Here is a simple example:

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass
from dataclass_wizard import YAMLWizard


yaml_input = """
name: foo
bar:
    - name: bar
"""


@dataclass
class Foo(YAMLWizard):
    name: str
    bar: list[Bar]


@dataclass
class Bar:
    name: str


instance = Foo.from_yaml(yaml_input)
print(f'Loaded: {instance}')
```

To install `dataclass-wizard` along with `pyyaml`, you can include the `yaml` extra:

```
pip install dataclass-wizard[yaml]
```

Comment: The thing is in my example `dataclass` actually works fine, but I hate them with passion as you can't inherit dataclass classes if the parent has a default value set. I like `pydantic` but if I use it, I basically have to stop using its basic functionality.

Comment: On the note about `dataclass` inheritance, I do agree it's kind of a problem when a parent class has any default values set. This is somewhat alleviated by the introduction of the [`kw_only`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#module-contents) param introduced in Python 3.10, but I agree that it's still an issue due to how dataclasses work in general.